# How to convert an old mod-python page to something more current? And to what -- WSGI?

Tags: apache, apache2, python

A long time ago -- it seems like a lifetime ago -- I wrote a page using Apache, mod-python and python 2.  It's still there (http://hex.kosmanor.com/hex-bin/board).  But after a long hiatus, I have updates I want to make, and it seems worthwhile to update the implementation too.

I'm just wondering what's the current best practice, and if there's a quick way, or at
least a tutorial somewhere, for making the switch.

Comment: Are you sure you want to stick with Python?  That looks like something that would run very well with static HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I'm guessing it would be easier to stick with Python compared to learning a new language and way of doing things.  I've never touched JavaScript so it would be entirely new.